# Should I try F# with MVC3 and ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, f#

I am working on a new project for contract. Usually I go with c# asp.net and razor. The problem is, my portfolio says. C# C# C# C# over and over. I figure portfolio wise it may be helpful to have a little more variety. The other side is, a functional language seems to be an interesting approach since asp.net MVC3 is very function oriented as far as the controllers are concerned. So, has anyone tried using F# for this and did it turn out to be helpful or just get in the way?

I ask, because the controllers seem to benefit from being functional, while the models seem to benefit from an object oriented language.

Comment: try it in your spare time as an hobby project. don't try it if you're working for a client!

Comment: I'm not really worried about the learning curve, sorry should have mentioned. The language is pretty easy from what I've seen. I just mean from a design point does it have any merit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote some examples of using MVC3 with a mix of F# and C# and it works quite well and I also created a template that can be used as a starting point (which should appear on Visual Studio Gallery soon):

- [F# Empty Web Application](http://tomasp.net/files/fsharpemptyweb.vsix)

There are some nice things about using F# in the implementation of model/controllers:

- F# types such as records make it very easy to implement the domain model
- You can also use F# asynchronous workflows to implement async controllers (see [this snippet](http://fssnip.net/4z))

A slightly annoying thing is that the support for LINQ in the current version of F# is a bit limited (writing complicated queries with lots of joins and grouping isn't easy). However, you can nicely use dynamic operator if you're calling stored procedures (see for example [this blog post](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-sql.aspx)).

(I also wrote some articles about this that are not published yet - I can send you a draft if you drop me an email at tomas@tomasp.net)